# how to uninstall plugin while wordpress dashboard is not working ? and ftp credential errors

Tags: ftp, wordpress

I have installed a bad plugin and after that my WordPress site along with admin panel dashboard is not working, here is my website admin panel 
http://www.apiculture-pour-tous.com/wp-admin/
I used same credentials for to ftp wordpress file but ftp shows credential errors.If any one can tell me how to uninstall plugin without admin panel and ftp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***edit***
just re-read your message. You will need `ssh` access in order to install WP-CLI, so don't know how helpful this is without it.

---

I advise you to install [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org), not just for this specific problem, but because it rules. It's a command line interface for Wordpress, meaning you can manage every aspect of your site from your terminal/shell.

In this case all you would need to do is run this command:

```
wp plugin deactivate <broken-plugin>
```

Fortunately, installation does not require you to login to the backend at all, so this should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the MySQL server that's hosting your WordPress installation data, you can get a list of active plugins with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';
```

to deactivate all plugins, you can do something along the lines of

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = 'a:0:{}' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';
```

as I recall.

If you are only wanting to disable one plugin, you can CAREFULLY edit the text for 'active_plugins' and UPDATE accordingly.